# Advanced Custom Fields / Wordpress - Conditional variable on meta query

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to query posts based on dates. The posts are events and must have a start date (**'date'**) and an optional end date (**'end_date'**).

I want to hide posts that have passed either their start date OR the end date if that is also in use, so I'm using a simple conditional to check for the end date field, however this is being ignored and only showing posts with just a start date (**'date'**)...

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d")-1,date("Y")));

// Check which date to use when comparing with $currentdate for hiding posts (as end_date might not always be in use for events)

if(get_field( 'end_date' )) {
    $date = 'end_date';
}
else {
    $date = 'date';
}

$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key' => $date,
        'compare' => '>',
        'value' => $currentdate,
        'type' => 'DATE',
    )
);
```

EDIT - Tried a nested meta query checking if the end_date field exists but its now igorning posts with just a start dead and my head hurts

```
$meta_query = array(            
    'relation' => 'OR',
    //Check for posts with start date ('date') and no end date
    array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key'   => 'date',
            'value' => $currentdate,        
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
        ),
    ),  
    //Check for posts with start date ('date') and an end date ('end_date')
    array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key' => 'date',  
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $currentdate,
            'compare' => '>',
        ),
    )
);
```

UPDATE AND FIX - Make sure to use DATE as the 'type', and using IN / NOT IN operators. Working exactly as expecting.

```
$meta_query = array(            
    'relation' => 'OR',
    //Check for posts with start date ('date') and no end date
    array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key'   => 'date',
            'value' => $currentdate,        
            'compare' => '>',            
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'compare' => 'NOT IN',            
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    ),  
    //Check for posts with start date ('date') and an end date ('end_date')
    array( 
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array( 
            'key' => 'date',              
            'compare' => 'IN',            
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $currentdate,
            'compare' => '>',            
            'type' => 'DATE'
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Your approach makes little sense - you are determining this for _one_ post there, _before_ the query - the query that is supposed to find those posts to begin with.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess I could run a nested meta query checking for values not in end_date

Comment: Meta query allows to use compare operator `NOT EXISTS`, so you could probably use that to differentiate between records that do have an end date set, and those that don't.

Comment: Updated with a nested query

Comment: Not sure if just `array( 'key' => 'date', ),` will work as intended. Documentation says the default for `compare` is `=`, so I think you might be checking whether `date` contains an empty string there?

Comment: The second part of the query is the part that is working as expected if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: U[dates and fixed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.